# Firestore Where Statement with Rules?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I have a Firestore query:

```
firebase.firestore()
    .collection('files')
    .where("design_id", "==", design.id)
    .get();
```

which gets a list of files, where the data looks like so

```
{
design_id: "P6oShXH081Mbssxs2zcp",
name: "all-teachers-like-brains.png",
type: "image",
user_id: "1uD82gAXORYsyimX5Dw23DDAimx1"
}
```

What I want to do is make sure that only the user that can access them is the one where the uid matches the user_id in the document.

For this, I have the following rules (version 2)

```
{
  match /files/{document=**} {
      allow read, delete: if fileBelongsToUser();
  }

function fileBelongsToUser() {
      return get(/databases/$(database)/documents/files/{document=**}).data.user_id == request.auth.uid;
    }
}
```

I'm still getting permission denied though and I cannot figure out why.  Are my rules preventing a where statement?

Comment: If you use the simulator does it pass the rules?

Answer (score 3):

[Firebase security rules are not filters](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-query#rules_are_not_filters).  You can't limit the documents accessed by a query by applying rules.  If any document from a query would not be allowed by rules, the entire query fails.  So, the query needs to request only documents that would be allowed by rules.

So, if your rule says that the uid must equal the field `user_id` in the document, your query must filter documents using that criteria:

```
firebase.firestore()
    .collection('files')
    .where("design_id", "==", design.id)
    .where("user_id", "==", uid)
    .get();
```

where `uid` above is the currently authenticated user's UID.